# UnsupportedMethod error when deploy scrapy project in EC2

Tags: scrapy

I was trying to deploy my Scrapy code to AWS by using scrapyd, but I got into this issue I could not figure out. It has been two days. I saw similar problems on the web, but did not find any helpful solution to fix this issue.

```
2016-02-15 08:41:20+0000 [HTTPChannel,1,xx.xxx.x.xxx] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1730, in allContentReceived
    req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 826, in requestReceived
    self.process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 189, in process
    self.render(resrc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 238, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 17, in render
    return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 19, in render
    r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 249, in render
    raise UnsupportedMethod(allowedMethods)
twisted.web.error.UnsupportedMethod: ['HEAD', 'object', 'POST']
```

I have tried to run the scrapy code alone in both my macbook, and EC2 server. It  works in both cases. It's just not working when I use my macbook to schedule a job in EC2. 
[These](http://bgrva.github.io/blog/2014/04/13/deploy-crawler-to-ec2-with-scrapyd/) are the steps I followed to set things up.

Comment: [Similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/yJY2ymX_qfc/uDjdIbJ4txQJ)

Comment: This is a similar problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/yJY2ymX_qfc/uDjdIbJ4txQJ